# In YII how to create empty batch of database rows at once without a loop...?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I'm new to YII, I want to create batch of database rows at once with foreign key id. How to do it without a loop? 

Ex.: In GRN if I enter `qty=30`, it should create 30 records in database(with that item id), so later I can enter the item SERIAL numbers.
**How to create 30 records at once with item FK without loop?**

Comment: Not clear, can you post some code..?

Comment: create a new Obj and call obj->save() ? to create an empty record. make sure there is no validators

Comment: Ex. in GRN if i enter qty=30,it should create 30 records in database(with that item id),so later i can enter the item SERIAL numbers.HOW TO CREATE 30 RECORDS AT ONCE WITH ITEM FK WITHOUT LOOP

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want a loop?

Comment: no i can do it with a loop... :) i just want to know if there's a way to do it without a loop...

Comment: I think you must use the loop to save the 30 records

Comment: Oh..if qty =500,loop should run 500 times(will it slow?)

Comment: Yep...it may slow down your application....

Comment: oh...no other way to do it??? plz friends...